# String lookup into unknown charset html content

Tags: php, string, find, character-encoding

I'm using strpos to lookup for string into web page bodies. 50% it fails, although the search string is present.
I have tried to strtolower both search string and searched content, same results.
Probabily the problem arises when dealing with different charsets...

Assuming:
- search string charset is unknown
- searched content charset is unknown
- charset could be any ISOxx, UTF-8, Shift-JIS

Is there a bulletproof function to find a substring?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) to detect the encoding first, then convert to the encoding you would like to use (using iconv or mb_convert_encoding) and search for the pattern in that encoding.

Answer (score 0):

yup convert the html to utf8/latin1 first, grab the content encoding from the Content-Type header or from the meta tag, convert to utf8/latin1 using iconv, then stop worrying about it

Comment: - some ill behaved pages don't use the content-type
- will it work also for SJIS pages?